# how to implement kafka template in spring project without spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

my project is implemented in spring.now i want use kafkatemplate. so i added below dependency in pom.xml but import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate gives an error at package com.kafka.config as "The type org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of Spring Framework you are using.

1.0.0 is no longer supported.

- Use 1.3.x (currently 1.3.8) with Spring Framework 4.3.x
- Use 2.1.x (currently 2.1.11) with Spring Framework 5.0.x
- Use 2.2.x (currently 2.2.1) with Spring Framework 5.1.x

Generally, it's better to use something that will manage the transitive versions for you, such as Maven or Gradle.